# How to fetch parameters provided in URL of jquery load functionality?

Tags: jquery, load

I am using the JQuery load functionality to load content of one page into another. My main page (index.html) has a div tag with id 'abcd'. I need to load contents of another page (page1.html) into the div tag specified. So, I write the following code :-

```
$('#abcd').load('page1.html?title=xyz','',function(){})
```

Note that I am also passing parameter 'title=xyz' alongwith the URL of the page to load. I need to get this parameter and work with it in page1.html content. How can I fetch this in page1.html page?

Comment: html not run on server side, use php

Comment: Hi
I am able to load contents of page1.html but not able to access the parameters.

Comment: which parametrs you wnat to access ? you have that parameters at the moment you make the url

Answer (score 1):

define a global varible e.g

```
<script>
var title =t'xyz'

$('#abcd').load('page1.html?title='+title,'',function(){})

</script>
```

you can access `title` variable in after page1.html load

On the other hand it might not be possible to do this with html if you want to change the content of page1.html, but still can be done using js hacks

if you provide how you want to use title in page1.html , I can help more

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Let me explain my case. I have a single page index.html with a div tag with id 'abcd'. The page has seperate buttons to load seperate pages into this div tag. For example, I click on button A, I load A.html into this div tag. If I click on button B, I load B.html into this div tag. All these multiple pages then load a single common page (page1.html) into the same div tag present in index.html. Now, I am adding parameter 'title' to load function in these multiple pages - A.html, B.html, so that I can track the previous page inside page1.html.

Comment: For example.
From index.html, I load A.html using
    $('#abcd').load('A.html,'',function(){})
From A.html, I load page1.html using
    $('#abcd').load('page1.html?title=A'+title,'',function(){})

Now, I need to access this title in order to track my previous page, i.e., A.html in this case. I hope I am able to clarify my case. Thanks in advance!